# Can you control the sensor of scrying?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, divination

Scrying creates a sensor. It says:

> the spell creates an invisible sensor within 10 feet of the target. You can see and hear through the sensor as if you were there. The sensor moves with the target, remaining within 10 feet of it for the duration.

What level of control do you have over that sensor? Can you move it to any point within 10 feet of the target, for example to be able to read in a book they are reading, or to maximize the area around the target that you can look at? If not, where would the sensor appear, and how would it follow the target?

Comment: I’ve removed the wizard tag since the question is not about wizards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You don't seem to have much control

You cite the important part, and along with

> You can see and hear a particular creature you choose

the spell only seems to guarantee that:

- The sensor will have a (good) view **of the target creature**.
- The sensor will be within 10 feet.

So no guarantee of reading their book, it's up to chance (i.e. the DM).

### But you can make it work

So you've scryed the target and see a book in front of him.
Well, that means you have seen their surroundings, the location.
Now you can cast *Scrying* again in the location mode:

> Instead of targeting a creature, you can choose a location you have
> seen before as the target of this spell. When you do, the sensor
> appears at that location and doesn't move.

And it shouldn't be a problem to specify a position for the sensor so that you have a clear view of the text.

Comment: If the interest is just in reading the book, instead of casting another *Scrying* one can use *Clairvoyance*, in "seeing mode", using a lower spell slot.

Comment: That works fine provided you're within a mile of the target.  Scrying can reach across the world, though.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym Right, I did not consider that.

Comment: Our DM is more generous here and allows moving the sensor around. I agree, likely not strict RAW, but no stretch to rule this way either. It might be worthwhile adding that it likely would not break anything to allow it. It does make a difference mostly due to time pressure.